# Removing UIAlertView from keyWindow Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, uialertview, uiwindow

I am removing UIAlertView from UIWindow by using this code : -

```
UIAlertView *alert= (UIAlertView*)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]subviews]objectAtIndex:0];
    [alert removeFromSuperview];
```

After removing alertview  from key Window my Whole screen turns faded like suspended while alertview shown. Please tell me how can  i make my all screen normal.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove the alert like that. Even if you get it to work now it could easily break with any future update to iOS.

Instead, when you create and show the alert, keep a reference to it. Then, when you need to, call `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:`.